# How to find out the editorial times (for article review) of CS journals?

Tags: publications, peer-review

Elsevier has recently lunched a tool called [Journal Finder](http://journalfinder.elsevier.com/) by which researchers can use paper's title and abstract, and field of study to find a suitable journal for their manuscript. Here is the sample 
[image] in which the editorial time is 12 weeks. They surely maintain database for their own, but is there any other source we can do this for other non-Elsevier journals, like IEEE or ACM? I know WoS provides some information about it, but WoS's database accuracy is not yet clear to me since I have seen lots of inaccurate information in WoS reports (for instance, number of "review article" published is often inaccurate).

Comment: Why restrict this question to CS?

Comment: This would be useful tool if it was to cover all journals,  not just Elsevier.

Comment: @aeismail: maybe other disciplines have such features. Because I am unable to find such data on the Internet for my own need, I though maybe I can get some help. Looking for the answer

Comment: Many journals have started using "reject & resubmit" very liberally as an answer instead of "major revisions", for the only reason that it makes processing times look artificially faster. I feel that if we publish these statistics and rely on them, we will just encourage this scammy strategy. The correct term of comparison here should be "time between first submission and acceptance", not "time between last submission and acceptance".

Answer (score 5):

Once a year the Notices of AMS publish the backlog of mathematics research journals containing *inter alia* the data you are interested in.

The 2012 one is here:

http://www.ams.org/notices/201210/rtx121001473p.pdf

and the 2013 is here :

http://www.ams.org/notices/201310/rnoti-p1390.pdf

and both do list some journals in informatics including the non-Elsevier ones (e.g. the Springer's Acta Informatica).

Comment: what if we can start maintaining a database for that? using crowd wisdom?

Answer (score 3):

Elsevier has recently launched a new toolbox including lots of useful information about journals. If you visit any Elsevier journal's homepage (I assume it works for all Elsevier journals], you will see the following box there,
[image]

Click on it and select 'Speed' link and it takes you to another page like [here](http://journalinsights.elsevier.com/journals/1084-8045/speed) (example for JNCA journal). The following information let you know the latest turn around time of this particular journal.

[image]

Hope other journals start similar approach.
Thanks and hope you find this post useful.

Comment: I guess this is better than nothing. But if they really only disclose the average number of weeks to decision, it's not worth much if you don't know anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following link [Here](http://libguides.framingham.edu/content.php?pid=481207&sid=3943382). However, it is more about psychology and non-engineering journals. I with there was such an repository for CS.

Comment: Thanks remo, the 'Journal Rate' is an interesting tool, but not yet completed. It does not have much review and rating on journals.

Comment: Please expand upon your answer, perhaps by adding a note about what we might find upon following the link you provide?